# order grouping variable in R

Tags: r, grouping

I have a database like this:

```
ID    | familysize | age |  gender 
------+------------+-------------------+------------+-----+----------
1001  |     4      | 26  |     1
1001  |     4      | 38  |     2
1001  |     4      | 30  |     2
1001  |     4      | 7   |     1
1002  |     3      | 25  |     2 
1002  |     3      | 39  |     1   
1002  |     3      | 10  |     2
1003  |     5      | 60  |     1 
1003  |     5      | 50  |     2 
1003  |     5      | 26  |     2
1003  |     5      | 23  |     1 
1003  |     5      | 20  |     1 
1004  |    ....
```

I want to order this dataframe by age of people in each ID , so I use this command:

```
library(plyr)
require(plyr)
b2<-ddply(b , "ID", function(x) head(x[order(x$ age, decreasing = TRUE), ], ))
```

but when I use this command I lost some of observation. what should I do for ordering this database ?

Answer (score 1):

```
b2 <- b[order(b$ID, -b$age), ]
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The `arrange` function in `plyr` does a great job here. Order by `ID` after that by `age` but in a descending order.

```
arrange(b, ID, desc(age))
```